# Запретить в строке всё кроме текста и цифр

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on("keyup", '.create--post--title', function(e) {
    var title = $('.create--post--title').val();
});
```

Как проверить содержатся ли символы в строке и в случаи наличия выполнить `return;` , каким должно быть регулярное выражение?

Проверять всю строку в данном случае нецелесообразно, поэтому как проверять именно введённый символ?

Comment: Строка может содержать в себе только текст и больше ничего, по определению. Следовательно, чтобы запретить в строке всё кроме текста — просто ничего не делайте.

Comment: Чтобы проверить, что в строке title есть хотя бы один символ: `title.length > 0`

Comment: @andreymal вы вероятно не так поняли, принятый ответ это то что нужно

Comment: Это вы не так объяснили.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно так. Символ `!` означает отрицание. Т.е. ищем совпадения в диапазоне от a до z, от 0 до 9, от а до я... если совпало - идем дальше, если нет - возвращаемся. Ну само собой, надо сохранить в какую-то переменную input.length и после каждого keyup сравнить текущее значение с предыдущим, чтобы запускать проверку только если добавился символ, а не на каком-нибудь Backspace или Shift

Ну а `e.key` особая фишка keyup и определяет нажатую кнопку.

```js
$(document).on("keyup", '.create--post--title', function(e) {
  if( !e.key.match(/[a-z]|[0-9]|[а-я]/ig) ) { $('#moo').html('недопустимый символ'); return; }
  else { $('#moo').html(''); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="create--post--title">

<p id="moo"></p>
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает, что вам еще нужна проверка на язык) Чтобы не напечатали одновременно и русскими и англ буквами.